# How to copy an Azure DevOps build artifact to a Docker image build in the same pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, docker-build

In an Azure DevOps pipeline after downloading an artifact from a previous `stage` like this:

```yaml
- download: 'current'
    artifact: my_artifact
```

I want to reuse it in the `Dockerfile` of this [Docker build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops):

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: myConnection
    repository: myRepository
```

like this:

```
COPY *.whl /myDir/
```

After the `COPY` command the target directory is still empty. Where are the files from the artifact and how do I copy them in the *Dockerfile*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to copy the artifact from where it is downloaded to (`$(Pipeline.Workspace)/my_artifact`) to the `PATH` directory, of the `build` command (`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`):

```yaml
- bash: cp $(Pipeline.Workspace)/my_artifact/*.whl $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Alternatively use the [CopyFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) command:

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/my_artifact'
    contents: '*.whl' 
    targetFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```